# Smooth scrolling background image in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, cordova

I am very beginner in HTML5, phonegap app development. I am having one problem about background image scrolling in HTC device only. Looking at the logcat of my HTC device, I came across this:

```
06-17 16:47:13.709: WARN / dalvikvm (159): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true 06-17 16:47:14.420: WARN / dalvikvm (159): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
```

It happens when I scroll the background image, after 5 second I can not scroll the image also, its struct automatically. 
In HTC device only its happening, what might be the problem?? 
Anybody please help me to get solve  this issue..